# Aria and a11y techiniques not working in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-material, accessibility

I have an angular installation where two aria features aren't working.

```
<div class="custom-checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" class="cdk-visually-hidden">
</div>
```

Is still showing the checkbox and

```
  <a mat-list-item routerLink cdkFocusRegionStart class='link'>Focus region start</a>
  <a mat-list-item routerLink class='link'>Link</a>
  <a mat-list-item routerLink cdkFocusInitial class='link'>Initially focused</a>
  <a mat-list-item routerLink cdkFocusRegionEnd class='link'>Focus region end</a>
```

is tabbing through sequentially and not hitting 'initially focused' first

My module imports looks like this, with no errors.

```
imports: [
  BrowserModule,
  AppRoutingModule,
  MatIconModule,
  MatFormFieldModule,
  MatInputModule,
  MatSelectModule,
  BrowserAnimationsModule,
  TextFieldModule,
  A11yModule
],
```

can anyone help? I would appreciate it.

Comment: Did you make any progress? Just for the sake of correctness: The question regards Angular Material, not Angular itself.

Comment: nah, I dropped the project. The documentation for all the stuff is ridiculously bad

Comment: I think this question should be closed, since it's very specific to the author's situation, and they are not interested in debugging this issue any longer.

Comment: I mean its not specific to my situation, im just pretty sure the library doesnt work as expected

Comment: its just nobody cares about accessibility so nobody cares about this

Comment: If you're convinced that it's a bug in the library, the best course of action would be to [report it on github](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues), so the developers know about it and can take a look at it.